# How would I get all users whose first character in their logins is 'g'?

Tags: linux, redhat

Please, any one help me in getting all users whose first character in their logins is 'g' ?

Comment: be more specific. using what to get in what format?

Comment: ok, in a human readable format

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
cat /etc/passwd | cut -d ":" -f 1 | egrep "^g"
```

is enough?

Answer (score -1):

```
Grep '^g*' /etc/passwd
```

And you can change `/etc/passwd` with any path you want

Comment: Not quite what the question is asking for, they want the login name, not the entire line from `/etc/passwd` ...